# How to create folder structure for modules in angular10

Tags: angular8, angular9, angular10, angular11

I have two modules like education and transport. I want to create modules and components for these. How to create a perfect folder structure for these. If anyone knows please help.

```
education
->school
   --> 1std component 
   --> 2std component
   --> 3std component
->college
   --> arts component
   --> engg component 
   --> diploma component 


transport
->cycle
   --> small component 
   --> medium component 
   --> large component 
->bike
   --> pulsar component 
   --> honda component 
   --> hundai component
```

Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-atpxot?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts

Comment: You may upvote the accepted answer as well :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be following folder structure would be useful for you!

```
-app
  
-shared
  -services
  -pipes
  -components
  -models

-modules
  -education
    -components
        -school
        -college
    -models
        -education.model.ts
    -services
        -education-service.ts

    -education.component.ts // this component should act like a container
    -education.component.html
    -education.component.module.ts        
    -education.component.route.ts

  -transport
    -components
        -cycle
        -bike
    -models
        transport.model.ts
    -services
        transport.service.ts
        
    -transport.component.ts // this component should act like a container
    -transport.component.html
    -transport.component.module.ts        
    -transport.component.route.ts

-app.component.ts
-app.component.html
-app.module.ts
-app-routing.module.ts
```

Above folder structure gives a kind of micro-service architecture as well where each module having its own services/dependencies.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How to generate these modules and components by angular cli command?

Comment: What is the difference between 'shared>services'  and  'education->services ->education-service.ts' ?

Comment: May be following commands that you could run in sequence `ng g m modules/education/education` and `ng g c modules/education/components/school` and so on.

Comment: shared folder is optional here and contents of it are being assumed as general. Whereas education/transport folder contents are specific in accordance with the corresponding folder as given